# How to recursively list all the files in and get the files "on going"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a program that needs to search a directory and all its sub directories for files that have a certain extension. This is going to be used both on a local, and a network drive, so performance is a bit of an issue.

i know i can use this kind of option:

```
  foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
        path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        ///
    }
```

but my folders gonna have a lot of files so i wondered how to imlement this kind of search that return the files "on going" instead on waiting until all the search will finish (something like Queue)

Comment: `EnumerateFiles()` does that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that your method should return them one by one (assuming you understood EnumerateFiles() does that already). Use yield return:

```
public IEnumerable<string > Foo(string path)
{
     foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
        path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
     {
         // Add additional logic if you need here
         yield return file;
      }
}
```

That way, if you run with foreach on your method you'll get each file at a time and you can add additional logic in the method.

Comment: I want it will behave like Queue, meaning i don't want to wait until my method finish to scan all the folder and sub folders but return the files "in process"

Comment: This is exactly what the method I wrote in my answer does. You can run it from a different thread and add it to a queue in a shared memory and poke the queue for changes That way the files scanning won't wait for the foreach loop.